# Why does Convert.ToInt32(byte) work in code?

Tags: c#, c#-2.0, int32

I've been trying to figure out how mscorlib `Convert.ToInt32(byte)` works given I only have access to .Net 2.0 for a project. Trying to use a .Net reflector to open that dll has resulted in no help so far in trying to see how .Net handled it in .Net 4.5 (which again, I don't have access to for this project).

Could someone explain how Convert.ToInt32(byte) works to convert and create a 32 bit signed int from a byte and how in code I can do this?

I've noticed there is a huge difference in the code below. Is it just a lower and upper bounds set for int32 and returns 0 if outside?

```
Console.WriteLine(
     Convert.ToInt32(buffer[i]).ToString() + 
                                         " " + 
     BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, i).ToString()
 );
```

[image: Convert.ToInt32 vs BitConverter.ToInt32]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From MSDN documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32(v=vs.80).aspx

BitConverter.ToInt32 takes 4 bytes starting at the position in the array you give it and converts it to a signed integer.

Convert.ToInt32 takes 1 byte and "expands" it to a Int32 type.

Given a byte array of length 4, called buffer, then BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0)

would compute the following:

```
buffer[3] * 16777216 + buffer[2] * 65536 + buffer[1] * 256 + buffer[0]
```

Convert.ToInt32(buffer[0]) on the other hand would compute the following:

```
(Int32)buffer[0]
```

Comment: 'Convert.ToInt32 takes 1 byte and "expands" it to a Int32 type.' 

Yes but how in code?

Comment: Converting a byte to int is a simple cast.

Comment: Sorry late night, I should have known. Threw myself off, ty.

Comment: @Euthyphro You could just look at the [source code of `Convert.ToInt32`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Convert.cs#L1043) ;-)

Comment: I did, but I didn't sleep for 24 hours and thought something is wrong it returns the same value. I even said that much in my question lol.

Answer (score 1):

`BitConverter.ToInt32(byte[] buffer, int index)` always takes 4 bytes, `Convert.ToInt32(byte b)` takes just 1.

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.ToInt32()` converts a specified value to a 32-bit signed integer.
while `BitConvertor.ToInt32()` returns a 32-bit signed integer converted from four bytes at a specified position in a byte array.

Here is the MSDN documentation for both with example[BitConvertor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[Convert.ToInt32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toint32(v=vs.110).aspx)